# Bottom tab bar moves up when keyboard opens in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

Without changing the android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" to adjustPan i want to stop the bottom tab bar resizing.

`<KeyboardAvoidingView>` also not working as expected.

can anyone give solution.

I am using react-native-router-flux

"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-native": "^0.59.2",

Comment: So you want to open the keyboard "on top" of your application?

Comment: yes, but what happening is when i open the key board then bottom tab bar moves up along with keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Update your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
 android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

inside `application -> activiry`

Comment: `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` is already there in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file. I can't change `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` because i want to resize the screen content while opens the keyboard